# Тире при противопоставлении.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Тебя не заденет,а меня()да.

Не могу понять,ставится ли здесь знак препинания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не тире при противопоставлении, это тире интонационное. Противопоставление у Вас с союзом а, вместо союза могло бы стоять тире:Тебя не заденет - меня заденет.Если речь только о знаке препинания,то он факультативен. Если нужно логически выделить местоимение, после него делаем паузу и ставим тире, если не нужно - не ставим.

Comment: Спасибо большое